# Page break inside td element

Tags: html, css

I need to apply page break inside td element and it's not working. Is there a solution for this?

Here is what I want to implement:

```
<table>  
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>
         <div>content 1</div>
         <div style="page-break-after:always;"></div>
         <div>content 2</div>
         <div style="page-break-after:always;"></div>
         <div>content 3</div>
       </td>
     </tr>
     ...
     ...
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I've tried out your code and it actually works fine. You can try it out by looking at the print review in chrome. If your goal was to get whitelines between the contents you can use `<br />` after each content div.

Comment: Thanks, ya it works in chrome. But can it work in firefox? I have to make it work in firefox.

Comment: Page break inside tables is not well supported in every browser. If you know haw many rows there are, you can create another table after a specific index.

Comment: it says [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after) that the basics (like page-break-after: always;) is supported on firefox. So it should work

Comment: ok, thank you very much. But it's still not working. If you find a solution for this you do let me know.